# JavaFX KeyCode for percent (%)

Tags: javafx, keycode

I want to detect when certain keys are pressed. I can't seem to find a `KeyCode` for the percent (%) sign. I have scoured the JavaFX 8 [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html), and there is no Enum constant for `PERCENT`like I would expect. Google was not helpful either. Is there something special about % that I don't know about?

```
@FXML
private void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getCode().isDigitKey() && !evt.isShiftDown()) {
        String number = evt.getText();
        numberAction(number);
    }
    if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DECIMAL)) {
        decimalAction();
    }
    if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.PERCENT)) {
        percentAction();
    }
}
```

The Enum `KeyCode.PERCENT` does not exist.

Comment: Got any code to share? I faced similar issues a while ago. It would help if you start us with some code.

Comment: @mohsenmadi not sure it really helps, but I added some code to my question. I'm just wanting a `KeyCode` for percent (Shift+5) on my keyboard. I can detect Shift+5 using a `KeyCombination`, but I want to use a `KeyCode` for last key pressed.

Comment: I see a good solution below by @fabian, or you can even use getText() on input to determine if the pressed key is %. True though, it seems no clean solution exists to treat all keys using the same coding approach.

Comment: This just seems like a bug to me. There is a KeyCode for the shift state of every number except for 5 (%). There is even one for "^" (`KeyCode.CIRCUMFLEX`).

Comment: All KeyCode constants represent unshifted keys.  Although it is rare to see a dedicated key for something like the circumflex on US keyboards, there are layouts, especially outside the US, which have such a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the `keyPressed` event, use the `keyTyped` event and use [`KeyEvent.getCharacter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--) to get the result independent from keyboard layout:

```
@FXML
private void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    ...
    if ("%".equals(evt.getCharacter())) {
        percentAction();
    }
}
```

(You need to modify your fxml file of course.)

Comment: Thanks @fabian. This will work. I was able to work around it in a manner similar to this.

Answer (score -1):

Did u try this?

```
YOUR_CONTROLLER.setOnKeyPressed(event ->{
        if((event.getCode() == KeyCode.DIGIT5) && event.isShiftDown())
            System.out.println("It's work");

});
```

And yes, u can't find KeyCode for this symbol because to write it you should to press more then 1 key (:

UPDATE:
You also can try this:

```
YOUR_CONTROLLER.setOnKeyPressed(event ->{
        if((event.getText().equals("%"))
             System.out.println("It's work");
});
```

Comment: This solution is a rather bad one... It depends on the keyboard layout and will fail e.g. for the [AZERTY layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)

Comment: So, the key is DIGIT and isShiftDown, now which key is it?

Comment: Apparently I can't :-)

Comment: @GVArt, But like I mentioned above, there is a KeyCode for the shift state of every number except for 5 (%). These would also require the shift key.